# How to specify "Target" of Mogenerator generated files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, mogenerator

I have a xcode project with multiple targets (for logic and app unit tests).

I am also using core data with the mogenerator plugin to autogenerate source files from the .xcdatamodel.

The generate files are not being generated with any of the "target" flags selected. This causes build errors.

Is anyone aware of a solution to this. I would like to be able to indicate which targets the generated files should be included in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out. You can specify the target of the .xcdatamodel file using "Get Info". Whatever targets are specified for the model are also specified for the generated files.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in Xcode 4?  There doesn't appear to be a spot to specify the target membership in Xcode 4.

Comment: Answering my own comment/question here.  The lack of a target picker appears to be a bug in Xcode 4.0.x (it is there in 4.2).  But you can work around the problem by removing the model from your project and re-adding it.  In the add dialog there is a target membership picker.